# Which is correct approach & or &amp; in Wordpress urls

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect

As I figured out, this gives me problems on the landing page ($tab get's to variables stack as ['amp;tab'] instead of ['tab'] ):

```
wp_redirect("admin.php?page=booking-manager&amp;tab=customers");
```

If I do debug it with:

```
$tab = isset($_GET['tab']) ? $_GET['tab'] : "";
echo nl2br(print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE));
die("TAB:$tab");
```

I get:

```
Array
(
[page] => booking-manager
[amp;tab] => customers
)
TAB:
```

So I had to use it without ampersanding to make if work:

```
wp_redirect("admin.php?page=booking-manager&tab=customers");
```

While for onClick and FORM action attributes, & ampersanding is working:

onClick:

```
onClick="window.location.href='<?php print(admin_url('admin.php?page=add-discount&amp;discount_type=1&amp;discount_id=0')); ?>'"
```

Form action:

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=add-customer&noheader=true'); ?>" method="post" id="form1">
```

I know that for the text content, I should use & ampersanding in HTML:

```
<p>Tom &amp; Jerry</p>
```

To make it W3C valid.
But I got lost in my knowledge about WordPress urls. Also, from other CMS, like Php-Fusion, I know that they force allways use & everywhere, and they parse it url's back to & if needed.

And the last question - how to Google about `&` VS `&amp;` - google do not give me results at all, I had to use "& ampersand", but still - how to Google about any code that Google would understand it.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` character is used as a delimiter between `key=value` pairs in the URL string, so escaping it will be harmful to your application, as you've seen. If you have a value the contains it you should encode it using **http encoding** (e.g., use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)) and not **html encoding**.

So, e.g., if you want to pass the parameter `name` with the value `'Tom & Jerry'`, `urlencode` would produce the string `'Tom+%26+Jerry'`.

Comment: So I should use just & in all three places of links, right? I mean in wp_redirect, onClick JavaScript target and in <a href= ?. Despite that it gives me problems only in wp_redirect. And what then will W3C validator will say if it have & (without ampersandings) in page content (these will be links, of course)